# Xcode 5 crashes on launch any idea what could be wrong?

Tags: xcode, macos

My installation of XCode 5 has started crashing with the message pasted below in pastebin link.

It's been keeping me trying to figure it out for the past 2 hours.

So far I tried:

1) Reinstall XCode
2) Force it not to open latest applications.

I am at a total loss.
[[http://pastebin.com/LST5q6wK]](http://pastebin.com/LST5q6wK%5d)

Comment: You could try deleting Xcode's Preferences file - I think it's at ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist

Comment: I did not remove the post. Could be someone from Pastebin.

Comment: XCode had an unsaved Workspace document. The steps below seemed to correct it.

/Users/YourUsername/Library/Autosave Information
 
Delete anything in there related to Xcode, such as files named Unsaved Xcode Document.xcworkspace. Restart Xcode and see if that fixes it.